# How to sort functions in C? "previous implicit declaration of a function was here" error

Tags: c, function

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I couldn't find anything that would help me.
I have a program with functions in C  that looks like this

```
function2(){
  function1()
}
function1 (){
  function2()
}

main () {
 function1()
}
```

It's more complicated than that, but I'm using recursion. And I cannot arrange the function in the file so that every function would only call functions that are specified above itself. I keep getting an error

```
main.c:193: error: conflicting types for 'function2'
main.c:127: error: previous implicit declaration of 'function2' was here
```

How do I avoid this? Thanks in advance for suggestions and answers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to declare (not define) at least one function before using it.

```
function2();                 /* declaration */
function1() { function2(); } /* definition */
function2() { function1(); } /* definition */

int main(void) { function1(); return 0; }
```

Comment: The definition of `function1()` also serves as a declaration.

Answer (score 7):

Foward declare your functions...

```
function1();
function2();

function2(){
  function1()
}
function1 (){
  function2()
}

main () {
 function1()
}
```

Comment: @abc the question was "how" not "why". For "why" I suggest reading up on the C language spec in general.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
function1();
function2();

function2(){
  function1()
}
function1 (){
  function2()
}

main () {
 function1()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Forward declare your functions, but by using *prototypes*. If you have a lot of them such that you can't handle this, this is the moment to think of your design and to create a .h file with all your prototypes. Use

```
int function1(void);
int function2(void);
```

if that was what you meant. `int function1()` already is different from that in C. Help the compiler such that he can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how C works. We need to declare the function before use. like when you use any variable, you must have declare first then  you would have use it.

Declaration:- 
function1();
function2();
and then put your own code.