# Modular programming in C (nested headers)

Tags: c, header

I'm creating a large program that's supposed to be simulating a MIPS pipeline. I'm trying to modularize my code as much as possible to keep things simple, but I'm having trouble compiling.

Currently my program contains the files:

- pipe.c --- Containing main
- IF.h
- ID.h
- EX.h
- MEM.h
- WB.h
- global.h --- containing global #define functions
- reg.h
- ALU.h
- control.h
- dMem.h
- fBuffer.h
- parser.h
- bin.h

I'm new to C programming but I have protected myself against multiple includes using #ifndef, #define, #endif in every header file. My problem is that when I compile I get errors claiming: "previous implicit declaration of..."

Many of the header files are used by multiple files, so I'm not sure if this is the issue. Is there some sort of big thing that I'm missing?

Comment: A *"previous implicit declaration of ..."* error is usually due to declaring a function twice.

Comment: Those are not very descriptive header names including the infamous `global.h`. You should consider better names to make your project easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

an *implicit* declaration means that there was something that *wasn't* declared in a header (instead, the compiler simply found the function).  a *previous* implicit declaration means that it's come across the declaration later, *after* assuming an implicit declaration for a "raw" function (or, i guess, as Doug suggests in the comments, another function with the same name).

there are a number of ways this can occur:

- maybe you didn't include the header in the associated file.  so `IF.c` doesn't include `IF.h`.  the compiler will read `IF.c` and create the implicit definition.  later, when it reads `IF.h` somewhere else, it will give this error.
- maybe you use a function in a file that doesn't include the relevant header.  so maybe `IF.h` defines `myfunction()`, but you use `myfunction()` in `dMem.c` and don't include `IF.h` there.  so the compiler sees the *use* of `myfunction()` in `dMem.c` before it sees the definition in `IF.h` when included in `IF.c`.
- without header files at all, you can get this with mutually recursive functions.  see [How to sort functions in C? "previous implicit declaration of a function was here" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387845/how-to-sort-functions-in-c-previous-implicit-declaration-of-a-function-was-her)
- as Doug suggested, you define two functions with the same name (and don't have a definition in a header).

basically, somewhere, somehow, the compiler got to a function before it got to the header with the associated declaration.  when it did find the header it realised things were messed up and generated the error.

(one classic source of header errors is cut+paste the "ifdefs" from one file to another and forget to change the name...)

[reading your question again i assumed you'd only listed the header files.  but now i see that is *all* the files you have.  why do you have so many more headers than source files?  typically each source file is associated with one or two headers that contain the declarations for the functions it defines (although it will likely import others that it needs for support).  this is unrelated to your compiler error, but it sounds like maybe you need to split your source up.  it also suggests that either i have misunderstood you, or you are misunderstanding how headers are typically used.]