# I have an error with the local Boolean code in my c code

Tags: c

The context is that I'm doing a dungeon and dragons minigame for a single player. In the decomposing I get that:

> prototipo.c: 313: 6: error: conflicting types for 'esObjeto'
>
> bool esObjeto (int ubicacionMatriz, int * personaje) {
>
> ^ ~~~~~~~
>
> prototype.c: 218: 15: note: previous implicit declaration of 'esObjeto' was here
>
> verdad = esObjeto (place, hero);
>
> ^ ~~~~~~~

Assuming that:

```
int place = int ** matrix [i] [j];

int * hero = who takes life, experience, portions, damage and defense.
```

But still throws an error.

Any solution?

```
bool esObjeto(int ubicacionMatriz, int * personaje){
if(ubicacionMatriz==2){
    Porciones(1);
    return true;
}
else if(ubicacionMatriz==3){
    Tesoro(3);
    return true;
}
else if(ubicacionMatriz>=4 && ubicacionMatriz<=8){
    Luchar(ubicacionMatriz, personaje);
    if(personaje[0]>0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
else{
    return false;
}}
```

Comment: The first time you mention `esObjeto` is on line 218. Then, when you actually wish to declare it on line 313 it is considered a different declaration. Move the code from line 313 to be before line 218.

Comment: You used the function before you declared it.

Comment: [Sorting functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4387898/1460794) in c.

Comment: It's not really C++ if the filename  ends in `.c`, right?

Answer (score 0):

> prototype.c: 218: 15: note: previous implicit declaration of 'esObjeto' was here
>
> ```
>   verdad = esObjeto (place, hero);
> ```

According to older C language (not C++) you can call a function without first providing a prototype for the function. The compiler can see the parameter types and assumes that the return value is an `int`. This is called "an implicit declaration".

Kind of works, if the "guess" is correct.

However, later in the file it sees

```
bool esObjeto(int ubicacionMatriz, int * personaje)
```

and notices that its previous assumption was not correct. The function actually returns a `bool` and not an `int`. So now it has compiled the call in the previous function incorrectly.

Oops!!

---

A solution to this is to move the function declaration to before it is used. Or at least provide a prototype at the beginning of the file, so the compiler can know about the return type.